# Update only Chosen Columns from Parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure that updates a table that depends on what parameters are used.

Example Table and Data below:

```
create table test_upd_tab
(
    co1 varchar2(100)
  , co2 varchar2(100)
  , co3 varchar2(100)
  , co4 varchar2(100)
  , co5 varchar2(100)
  , dat1 varchar2(100)
  , dat2 varchar2(100)
);

insert into test_upd_tab ( co1, co2, co3, co4, co5, dat1, dat2 ) values ( 'co1', 'co7',  'co13', 'co19', 'co25', 'dat31', 'dat37' );
insert into test_upd_tab ( co1, co2, co3, co4, co5, dat1, dat2 ) values ( 'co2', 'co8',  'co14', 'co20', 'co26', 'dat32', 'dat38' );
insert into test_upd_tab ( co1, co2, co3, co4, co5, dat1, dat2 ) values ( 'co3', 'co9',  'co15', 'co21', 'co27', 'dat33', 'dat39' );
insert into test_upd_tab ( co1, co2, co3, co4, co5, dat1, dat2 ) values ( 'co4', 'co10', 'co16', 'co22', 'co28', 'dat34', 'dat40' );
insert into test_upd_tab ( co1, co2, co3, co4, co5, dat1, dat2 ) values ( 'co5', 'co11', 'co17', 'co23', 'co29', 'dat35', 'dat41' );
insert into test_upd_tab ( co1, co2, co3, co4, co5, dat1, dat2 ) values ( 'co6', 'co12', 'co18', 'co24', 'co30', 'dat36', 'dat42' );
commit;
```

That table will be updated using the package below:

```
create or replace package xxtest_upd_pkg
as
    procedure update_tab (p_co1  test_upd_tab.co1%type
              , p_co2  test_upd_tab.co2%type
              , p_co3  test_upd_tab.co3%type
              , p_co4  test_upd_tab.co4%type
              , p_co5  test_upd_tab.co5%type
              , p_dat1 test_upd_tab.dat1%type
              , p_dat2 test_upd_tab.dat2%type
                );

end xxtest_upd_pkg;

create or replace package body xxtest_upd_pkg
as
    procedure update_tab (p_co1  test_upd_tab.co1%type
              , p_co2  test_upd_tab.co2%type
              , p_co3  test_upd_tab.co3%type
              , p_co4  test_upd_tab.co4%type
              , p_co5  test_upd_tab.co5%type
              , p_dat1 test_upd_tab.dat1%type
              , p_dat2 test_upd_tab.dat2%type
                )
    as
    begin

        UPDATE  test_upd_tab
        SET     co1  = p_co1
              , co2  = p_co2
              , co3  = p_co3
              , co4  = p_co4
              , co5  = p_co5
        where   dat1 = p_dat1
        and     dat2 = p_dat2;

    end update_tab;

end xxtest_upd_pkg;
```

However, sometimes, only some columns should be updated, and not all at the same time.
Something like below:

```
begin

-- only update co1 to co3 then don't touch co4 and co5
xxtest_upd_pkg.update_tab (p_co1  => 'x'
                         , p_co2  => 'y'
                         , p_co3  => 'z'
                         , p_dat1 => 'dat31' 
                         , p_dat2 => 'dat37');

-- only update co3 to co5 hen don't touch co1 and co2
xxtest_upd_pkg.update_tab (p_co3  => 'zz'
                         , p_co4  => 'a'
                         , p_co5  => 'b'
                         , p_dat1 => 'dat33' 
                         , p_dat2 => 'dat39');

-- update co3 to null 
xxtest_upd_pkg.update_tab (p_co3  => null                           
                         , p_dat1 => 'dat35' 
                         , p_dat2 => 'dat41');                          

end;
```

of course this results into the error below:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE_TAB'
```

P.S. I cannot use something like "NVL(p_co1, co1)", shown below because there are some instances i will really pass null values.

```
create or replace package body xxtest_upd_pkg

    update_tab (p_co1  test_upd_tab.co1%type default null
              , p_co2  test_upd_tab.co2%type default null
              , p_co3  test_upd_tab.co3%type default null
              , p_co4  test_upd_tab.co4%type default null
              , p_co5  test_upd_tab.co5%type default null
              , p_dat1 test_upd_tab.dat1%type
              , p_dat2 test_upd_tab.dat2%type
                )
    as
    begin

        UPDATE  test_upd_tab
        SET     co1  = nvl(p_col1, co1)
              , co2  = nvl(p_col2, co2)
              , co3  = nvl(p_col3, co3)
              , co4  = nvl(p_col4, co4)
              , co5  = nvl(p_col5, co5)
        where   dat1 = p_dat1
        and     dat2 = p_dat2;

    end update_tab;

end xxtest_upd_pkg;
```

How do I do this without using overloaded functions or Dynamic SQL?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did to resolve this was a combination of using `DEFAULT` Values and `CASE` Staements:

```
create or replace package xxtest_upd_pkg
as
    procedure update_tab (p_co1  test_upd_tab.co1%type                  -- required
                        , p_co2  test_upd_tab.co2%type  default 'N/A'
                        , p_co3  test_upd_tab.co3%type  default 'N/A'
                        , p_co4  test_upd_tab.co4%type  default 'N/A'
                        , p_co5  test_upd_tab.co5%type  default 'N/A'
                        , p_dat1 test_upd_tab.dat1%type                 -- required
                        , p_dat2 test_upd_tab.dat2%type                 -- required
                          );

end xxtest_upd_pkg;

create or replace package body xxtest_upd_pkg
as
    procedure update_tab (p_co1  test_upd_tab.co1%type  default 'N/A'
                        , p_co2  test_upd_tab.co2%type  default 'N/A'
                        , p_co3  test_upd_tab.co3%type  default 'N/A'
                        , p_co4  test_upd_tab.co4%type  default 'N/A'
                        , p_co5  test_upd_tab.co5%type  default 'N/A'
                        , p_dat1 test_upd_tab.dat1%type                 -- required
                        , p_dat2 test_upd_tab.dat2%type                 -- required
                          );
    as
    begin

        UPDATE  test_upd_tab
        SET     co1  = case when p_co1 = 'N/A' then co2 else p_co1 end
              , co2  = case when p_co2 = 'N/A' then co2 else p_co2 end
              , co3  = case when p_co3 = 'N/A' then co3 else p_co3 end
              , co4  = case when p_co4 = 'N/A' then co4 else p_co4 end
              , co5  = case when p_co5 = 'N/A' then co5 else p_co5 end
        where   dat1 = p_dat1
        and     dat2 = p_dat2;

    end update_tab;

end xxtest_upd_pkg;
```

So i can now call the package as below:

```
begin

-- only update co1 to co3 then don't touch co4 and co5
xxtest_upd_pkg.update_tab (p_co1  => 'x'
                         , p_co2  => 'y'
                         , p_co3  => 'z'
                         , p_dat1 => 'dat31' 
                         , p_dat2 => 'dat37');

-- only update co3 to co5 hen don't touch co1 and co2
xxtest_upd_pkg.update_tab (p_co3  => 'zz'
                         , p_co4  => 'a'
                         , p_co5  => 'b'
                         , p_dat1 => 'dat33' 
                         , p_dat2 => 'dat39');

-- update co3 to null 
xxtest_upd_pkg.update_tab (p_co3  => null                           
                         , p_dat1 => 'dat35' 
                         , p_dat2 => 'dat41');                          

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach.

Modify the signature of your update_tab procedure and add a flag for each column you want to update. Something like this.

```
procedure update_tab 
          (p_co1  test_upd_tab.co1%type,
           p_co1_flag VARCHAR2(1),   
           p_co2  test_upd_tab.co2%type,
           p_co2_flag VARCHAR2(1),
           p_co3  test_upd_tab.co3%type,
           p_co3_flag VARCHAR2(1),
           p_co4  test_upd_tab.co4%type,
           p_co4_flag VARCHAR2(1),
           p_co5  test_upd_tab.co5%type,
           p_co5_flag VARCHAR2(1),
           p_dat1 test_upd_tab.dat1%type,
           p_dat2 test_upd_tab.dat2%type
           );
```

Modify your update statement like this.

```
    UPDATE  test_upd_tab
    SET     co1  = CASE WHEN p_co1_flag = 'Y' then p_co1 ELSE  co1 END,
            co2  = CASE WHEN p_co2_flag = 'Y' then p_co2 ELSE  co2 END,
            co3  = CASE WHEN p_co3_flag = 'Y' then p_co3 ELSE  co3 END,
            co4  = CASE WHEN p_co4_flag = 'Y' then p_co4 ELSE  co4 END,
            co5  = CASE WHEN p_co1_flag = 'Y' then p_co1 ELSE  co5 END
    WHERE   dat1 = p_dat1
    AND     dat2 = p_dat2;
```

Now, for whatever columns you want to update you have to pass the Yes flag for that column.

```
xxtest_upd_pkg.update_tab (p_co1  => 'a',    
                                   p_co1_flag = 'Y',        
                                   p_co2  => 'm',
                                   p_co2_flag = 'Y',
                                   p_co3  => 'z',
                                   p_co3_flag = 'Y',
                                   p_co4  => 'DUMMY',
                                   p_co4_flag = 'N',
                                   p_co5  => 'DUMMY',
                                   p_co5_flag = 'N',
                                   p_dat1 => 'dat31',
                                   p_dat2 => 'dat37');
```

Now, only those columns will be updated for which you will pass a Y flag. The rest of the columns will be updated with their existing values.

Answer (score 0):

There probably aren't a lot of great options.

If you want to make the parameters optional, you need to specify a default.  In theory, you could identify an impossible but non-NULL value for each column, use that as the default, and then check that as part of your update.  But in practice, that tends to be difficult and you end up with a bunch of different "magic" values (-1 works for lots of numeric columns that only support positive values but not for columns that could legitimately have negatives; date '1800-01-01' works for a lot of dates unless you happen to have, say, a real estate database where some properties are a couple hundred years old).

You could use `NULL` as a default and then add an additional parameter that identifies which `NULL` values are "real" and which are defaults.  That could be, for example, a collection of the parameters that you want to really be set to `NULL`.

```
create type my_collection as table of varchar2(30);

xxtest_upd_pkg.update_tab (p_co3  => null
                         , p_co4  => 'a'
                         , p_co5  => null
                         , p_co6  => null 
                         , p_attr_to_null => my_collection( 'p_co6', 'p_col5' )
                         , p_dat1 => 'dat35' 
                         , p_dat2 => 'dat41');
```

Of course, that means that you'd be defining a collection type and that's a bit inelegant.  And now your procedure has to check whether the parameter is `NULL` and whether the parameter is listed in your `p_attr_to_null` collection.

Comment: hi @justin-cave yes i tried that too. i used -1 and "N/A" as default values for Numerical and Varchar2 Columns. I'll check on this a bit more.